# RSpec for Custom Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have custom validations in rails model:

```
validate :custom_validation_method

def custom_validation_method
  # do stuff here
end
```

How can I make RSpec for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test validations(any)

```
describe MyClass do
  it '#custom_validation' do
    expect(subject.valid?).to be_falsey
    #do stuff to subject to make it valid
    expect(subject.valid?).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.